# Auth_User - Leaving the Username field Blank

Tags: django

I'm actually just wondering if it would be possible to leave the username field blank in the auth_user table.

Currently, I'm leaving it blank but django takes the null field as a duplicate field so it only allows me to sign up one account and then throws:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username
```

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django `User`(contrib.auth.models.User) model extend `AbstractUser` which has `username` field defined as

```
username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
    help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and '
                '@/./+/-/_ characters'),
    validators=[
        validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'), _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
    ])
```

so if you need username field blank then you need to write custom user model. The instruction for this can be found at [Customizing authentication in Django-A full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)